# UISearchBar textfield height not increasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I am doing the following to change the height of UISearchBar and the textField inside it :

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [searchBarEmployee setNeedsLayout];
    [searchBarEmployee layoutIfNeeded];

    for(UIView *view in searchBarEmployee.subviews)
    {
        for(UIView *subview in view.subviews)
        {
            if([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
            {
                UITextField *txt = (UITextField*)subview;
                [txt setNeedsLayout];
                [txt layoutIfNeeded];
                CGRect rect = txt.bounds;
                rect.size.height = 80;
                txt.bounds = rect;
                txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
            }
        }
    }

    CGRect bound = searchBarEmployee.bounds;
    bound.size.height = 100;
    searchBarEmployee.bounds = bound;
}
```

But it is giving me this :

[image]

How to fix this ?

Comment: Are you using autolayout in this viewController? If so, you should manupulate constraints instead of frame/bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

**Obj-C;**

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [searchBarEmployee layoutSubviews];

    for(UIView *view in searchBarEmployee.subviews)
    {
        for(UITextField *textfield in view.subviews)
        {
            if ([textfield isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
                textfield.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, textfield.frame.size.width, 80.0f);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift;**

```
for subView in homeView.subviews where subView is UITextField {
    subView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: subView.frame.size.width, height: 80)
}
```

Comment: This is some sketchy, yet working code. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0 version of working answer:

```
  for view in (searchBar!.subviews) {
            for possibleTextField in view.subviews {
                if possibleTextField is UITextField {
                    let textField = possibleTextField as! UITextField
                    textField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 100) // New height here
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this tutorial, its a little bit of extra work customizing the search bar but worth it if your going to reuse it: https://www.appcoda.com/custom-search-bar-tutorial/